# Subnormal versus quasinormal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup.
$H$ is [subnormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_subgroup) if it exists a finite normal chain from $H$ to $G$.
$H$ is [quasinormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinormal_subgroup) if $HS=SH$ for all subgroup $S$ of $G$.

If $G$ is a finite group, then every quasinormal subgroup is subnormal.
What about the converse :

> **Question**: Is there a subnormal subgroup which is not quasinormal ?

Comment: Groups in which subnormal=quasinormal have been classified. They are called T-groups or "groups in which normality is a transitive relation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, let $K$ be a non-trivial finite group.
Let $\tau \in Aut(K \times K)$ defined by $\tau(k_1,k_2)=(k_2,k_1)$.

Then $H=K \times \{ e\}  \triangleleft K \times K \triangleleft (K \times K) \rtimes_{\tau} \mathbb{Z}_2 = G$, but $H.\mathbb{Z}_2 \neq \mathbb{Z}_2.H $

Answer (score 2):

For an explicit example, take $\;H:=\{(1)\,,\,(12)(34)\}\le S_4\;$ . Then this subgroup is subnormal since

$$H\lhd \{(1)\,,\,(12)(34)\,,\,(13)(24)\,,\,(14)(23)\}\lhd A_4\lhd S_4$$

but it is not quasinormal since if we take $\;K:=\langle(123)\rangle=\{(1)\,,\,(123)\,,\,(132)\}\;$ then

$$HK=\{(1)\,,\,(123)\,,\,(132)\,,\,(12)(34)\,,\,(243)\,,\,(143)\}$$

whereas

$$KH=\{(1)\,,\,(12)(34)\,,\,(123)\,,\,(134)\,,\,(132)\,,\,(234)\}\neq HK$$

Comment: Thank you for this explicit example.